# How to output CDATA using yattag library

Tags: python, xml, encoding, yattag

I'm trying with the following code to generate an XML file contains tags `</documents>`.

```
string = "dasdd Wonder asdf new single, “Tomorrow” #URL# | " \
    "oiojk asfddsf releases new asdfdf, “gfsg” | " \
    "Identity of asfqw who dasd off asdfsdf Mainland jtyjyjui revealed #URL#"

from yattag import Doc, indent
import html, re

doc, tag, text = Doc().tagtext()
with tag('author', lang='en'):
    with tag('documents'):
        for tweet in string.split(' | '):
            with tag('document'):
                tweet = html.unescape(tweet)
                text('<![CDATA[{}]]'.format(tweet))
result = indent(doc.getvalue(), indentation=' ' * 4, newline='\n')
with open('test.xml', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    f.write(result)
```

I wanted to add `CDATA` token around the text, but when I open the generated file using `Notepad++` instead of have the output as:

```
<document><![CDATA[oiojk asfddsf releases new asdfdf, “gfsg”]]></document>
```

it appears like (with HTML entities):

```
<document>&lt;![CDATA[oiojk asfddsf releases new asdfdf, “gfsg”]]</document>
```

I tried to use `HTML` library (`html.unescape` line) to discard the HTML entities but I wasn't able.

How can I solve this encoding issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `text` method always replaces '<' with `&lt;`. If you wanted no escaping of that kind, you would use the `asis` method instead (it inserts the string "as is"). But, in your case, it would be more appropriate to use Yattag's `cdata` method.

```
from yattag import Doc
help(Doc.cdata)
```

cdata(self, strg, safe=False) appends a CDATA section containing the supplied string.

You don't have to worry about potential `]]>` sequences that would terminate
    the CDATA section. They are replaced with `]]]]><![CDATA[>`.

If you're sure your string does not contain `]]>`, you can pass `safe = True`.
If you do that, your string won't be searched for `]]>` sequences.

So, in your case, you can do:

```
for tweet in string.split(' | '):
    with tag('document'):
        tweet = html.unescape(tweet)
        doc.cdata(tweet)
```